# Calculate the size of a polygon given the number and radius of circles that are on the perimeter

Tags: circles, polygons

How can i calculate the size of a regular polygon if i have N circles of same size and all the circles must be on the perimeter of the polygon.

Examples:
[image] 2 circles on hexagon

[image] 
3 circles on hexagon

Is there a equation that given the number of vertices on polygon (>= 3) and the number of circles (>=2) and radius of the circle, will output me the edge length of a such a regular polygon? Also it would be bonus if there would be a way to find the positions of the circles also.

Conditions for the hexagon and circle placement:

1. Hexagon must be minimal
2. Circles must not overlap
3. Circle centers must be on perimeter

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: In your first diagram, what prevents the polygon being vastly larger than my monitor, with both circles lying on the same edge, (so that the number of vertices is unknow-able)?

Comment: @EricTowers the vertices count is predetermined based on separate data so it cannot be predicted. But its unlikely to have more than 20 vertices. And also there will be an additional step, that if the polygon gets too large, it will be split into smaller inner and larger outer polygon. So unless there are thousands of circles, it will not grow too large.

Comment: What does size mean? Edge lenght? I think I read something like that in the body. How can a regular Polygon be "minimal"? The circles' centers being on the perimeter does not suffice as information. Being on the vertices could solve the problem. If you have n non-overlapping congruent circles on the n vertices of a regural n-gon. The edge of the polygon must be at least(or more_ equal in lenght with twice the radius. Exactly equal if they are tangent one on another. We need to know the circles' positions to give you an answer.

Comment: We need to know the number or vertices of the regular polygon, the number of circles, hopefully if the circles are tangent one on another. And the location of their centres.(Vertices probably).

Maybe give qualitative information on the circles' radii or say if they are congruent.

Comment: By minimal i mean as compact as possible. The circle centres are on perimeter, since the amount of circles can vary exact positions cannot be given. You can assume that atleast 1 circle is on the vertex(lets say the first circle is always on a vertex). I can have less than n or more than n or exactly n circles.

Comment: @MarkoTaht This was most unhelpful. I can only speculate what you mean.  With most compact do you mean leave the least area uncovered?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I think you could think of it that way. Basically if you have a n-gon and k circles with radius r, i want to find the smallest perimeter of the given n-gon such that if all the circle centers are placed on the perimeter, you cant make the perimeter any smaller, because the circles will start to overlap. the 2nd and 3rd conditions are iron clad and cannot be changed. but the 1st condition can be relaxed a bit for the ease of calculation if nessesary. So approximation of the minimal n-gon is also ok.

Comment: @MarkoTaht You still did not provide any help. If you do not specify the number of circles, their centres' position, the number of vertices and clarify what you want we cannot help you. If you have n vertices and n equal(equal radii) circles then the position of the centres to maximise the available radii is on the vertices and the radii are half the polygon's edge. by Kuhn Tucker conditions, and Differential Geometry. You are just trying to solve a system with too few equations and too many variables. Either give more information(helpful) OR do not ask so many things.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Well this is all the information i have. Given N-gon and K circles with radius R, what is the minimal or near minimal perimeter( or radius) of the poygon that can fit all the circle centers(location of these depends on the size of the polygon) on the perimeter without the circles overlapping. The first circle center is on a vertex.

If K = N then it is trivial, but if K > N or K < N then it it not trivial anymore. There is no more information to give. If the solution avoids overlaps and caps large enough to fit another circle, then its fine.

Comment: @MarkoTaht Maybe you read, or heard this problem somewhere from a non-english source or you imagined such a scenario. There is no unique solution. Maximum radius of circles make sense not minimum perimetre of the polygon. The solution since you did limit the circles to having the same radii. Is finding the maximum lenght line segments part of line of symmetry. If you have 2 circles the median to the opposite edge(extend the concept to any n-gon where n is odd) or the diagonal is the longest. The radius is half the lenght segment.

Comment: @MarkoTaht With K circles just draw an inscribed regular K-gon with the longest edge inside the original N-gon and the circles have half the radius of the edges.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I am the only person here trying to help Marko Taht. I can easily imagine jobsworth people just not caring because the question is not easily answerable. Which is the damage I am doing to at least 1 other anatomically modern human? I can only imagine that I am harming their aesthetics, etiquette, the way comme il faut, the admins, and moderators' time because they have to read what I am writting and the servers I am unececcesarily loading the with bits regardless of the amount of bits. I do not want any reputation I only want to help.

Comment: My comment above is not meant to hurt you nor @MarkoTaht. However, the StackExchange is not a forum for discussion: it is a Q&A website which admittedly aims at featuring high quality question and high quality answers. If someone needs a solution to the same problem of Marko and comes here and finds your comments posted as a solution (which they are not) they could be at least disappointed: if you want help Marko try to work directly towards its solution and when you reach it post it, or improve your reputation answering to other question and then post here your useful comments.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to calculate an exact length, because there is lot's of "wiggle room"! In the first picuture, for example, slightly increasing or decreasing the polygon side length still seems to produce an "acceptable" configuration.

Of course, what your problem description is missing is a rigorous definition of what "acceptable" is. From the pictures I assume

1. The centers of the circles must be on the perimeter of the polygon, and
2. the circles cannot overlap.

Using these conditions alone means that any sufficiently large edge length will work (I see no problem putting 100 circles of radius **1cm** onto a regular triangle with side lengh **100km**, for example).

So please specify the exact conditions for "acceptable" configurations, and if it isn't more than what I wrote, I think the only reasonable question would be to ask for the smallest edge length that can fulfill those conditions.

Comment: i added the conditions.